# How to use awk and grep on 300GB .txt file?

Tags: regex, unix, awk, grep, large-files

I have a huge .txt file, 300GB to be more precise, and I would like to put all the distinct strings from the first column, that match my pattern into a different .txt file.

```
awk '{print $1}' file_name | grep -o '/ns/.*' | awk '!seen[$0]++' > test1.txt
```

This is what I've tried, and as far as I can see it works fine but the problem is that after some time I get the following error:

```
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
    FILENAME="file_name" FNR=117897124 NR=117897124
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Custom script perhaps?

Comment: Could you give us a couple of sample lines from the file?

Comment: maybe replace that third step with `sort` and `uniq` instead of trying to do it in memory.

Comment: How big is the file after the `grep` ?

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast reply! Anyhow I tested the command it works perfectly... The thing is that the file is too large and after processing 5-10 GB of it, I always get the previously mentioned error. So I'm asking for an alternate way of doing the same thing with HUGE files.

Comment: The file is still too big. Even if I only execute

    awk '{print $1}'    

I get the same error.

Comment: @JovanAndonov Just curious - how many records does the file has?  What is the output of running `wc file_name` ?

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata). Your question is ok for both Stack Overflow and [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132556/how-can-i-get-the-first-column-of-a-300gb-txt-file), but pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you:

```
line(117897124) has to many fields (>32767).
```

You'd better check it out:

```
sed -n '117897124{p;q}' file_name
```

---

Use `cut` to extract 1st column:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1 < file_name | ...
```

<sub>**Note**: You may change `' '` to whatever the field separator is. The default is `$'\t'`.</sub>

Comment: Well... so far so good! :) I haven't received an error yet and it's processing the file as it's supposed too. I will tell you if this works or not when it's done.

Answer (score 2):

The 'number of fields' is the number of 'columns' in the input file, so if one of the lines is *really* long, then that could potentially cause this error.

I suspect that the `awk` and `grep` steps could be combined into one:

```
sed -n 's/\(^pattern...\).*/\1/p' some_file | awk '!seen[$0]++' > test1.txt
```

That might evade the `awk` problem entirely (that `sed` command substitutes any leading text which matches the pattern, in place of the entire line, and if it matches, prints out the line).

Comment: I have difficulties making it work. So just to make sure we are on the same page, I would like to get the part of the line that match my pattern from all lines in the first column of the file and I would also like to remove the duplicates. Is that what 's/\(^pattern...\).*/\1/p' some_file does? If so can you please help me into altering the above command with the following pattern /ns/.* ?

Comment: The first command (the `sed`) is intended to replace the complete line, which includes a match for your pattern (namely the `\(...\)`), with the contents of the match (the `\1`, which represents the content of the `\(...\)`), and print out the changed line with `/p`.  If there's no match, there's no print.  Therefore this command prints out only those lines which include a match, and those lines have been substituted to contain only the matched text.  If the text you're looking for is a field 1 starting `ns`, then this would be `s/\(^ns[^ ]*\).*/\1/p`

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that your `awk` implementation has an upper limit for the number of records it can read in one go of `117,897,124`.  The limits can vary according to your implementation, and your OS.

Maybe a sane way to approach this problem is to program a custom script that uses `split` to split the large file into smaller ones, with no more than `100,000,000` records each.

---

Just in case that you don't want to split the file, then maybe you could look for the `limits` file correspondent to your `awk` implementation.  Maybe you can define `unlimited` as the Number of Records value, although I believe that is not a good idea, as you might end up using a lot of resources...

Comment: +1 for split. This problem seems to be quite amenable to split and recombine.

Comment: That should work but I wanted to know if there is a way to achieve this without splitting the file :)

Comment: @JovanAndonov - understood.  Check my edit ;)  That file could be in different places, depending on your `awk` implementation, so I guess you will have to look at yours `awk` manual to find out where it is.  I hope this helps!

Comment: The limitation is on fields, not records. Splitting the file won't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough free space on disk (because creates a temp .swp file) I suggest to use Vim, vim regex has small difference but you can convert from standard regex to vim regex with this tool http://thewebminer.com/regex-to-vim

Comment: I have enough free space. So can you please explain to me or point me to a nice tutorial about vim?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says your input file contains too many fields for your awk implementation. Just change the field separator to be the same as the record separator and you'll only have 1 field per line and so avoid that problem, then merge the rest of the commands into one:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=RS} {sub(/[[:space:]].*/,"")} /\/ns\// && !seen[$0]++' file_name
```

If that's a problem then try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=RS} {sub(/[[:space:]].*/,"")} /\/ns\//' file_name | sort -u
```

There may be an even simpler solution but since you haven't posted any sample input and expected output, we're just guessing.